# RX Java with Retrofit-2 VS Normal Retrofit-2

Tags: android, android-layout, rx-java, retrofit2

I am currently using `Retrofit2` for `API` parsing. As I was asked to change it with `RxJava` + `Retrofit` for my new application. How can I achieve this. What is the benefits of using `RxJava` along with `Retrofit`.

Any help should be a greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using for normal `Retrofit` parsing

```
Retrofit.Builder builder =new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).client(httpClient).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
```

Comment: first start learning rxJava, watch this video to get started [link](https://news.realm.io/news/rxify-rxjava-operators-droid-boston-jain-2017/)

Comment: which version of rxjava?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I was asked to change it with RxJava + Retrofit for my new application. How can I achieve this.

Add `com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2` as a dependency in your project and configure it on your `Retrofit.Builder`:

```
addCallAdapterFactory(
    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
```

Then you can change your Retrofit interfaces from

```
Call<ReturnType> op(...)
```

to

```
Observable<ReturnType> op(...)
```

and instead of `enqueue()`ing the `Call`, subscribe the observable to get your requests flying.

> What is the benefits of using RxJava along with Retrofit

Retrofit service API calls integrate nicely with other rxjava code in your application. If you're not using rxjava elsewhere in your application, there's little benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and effective solution.